# Despite assigning a WndProc message a Result value of IntPtr(1) on a custom message, the process that called sendmessage gets a 0 return;

Tags: c#, wndproc

I have am trying to implement a variation on a keypress filtering application from c++ to c#. It uses a sendmessage() call to a window to determine whether to suppress the input or not.

```
public static int hookProc(int code, int wParam, ref keyboardHookStruct lParam)
{
    if (code < 0)
    {
        return CallNextHookEx(hhook, code, wParam, ref lParam);
    }
    IntPtr result = SendMessage(sourceInstane, Win32.WM_HOOK, wParam, ref lParam);
    if (result.ToInt32() == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(hhook, code, wParam, ref lParam);
}
```

I receive the message in the main form just fine. However every attempt to return a value in the "message.Result" property comes back as 0 in the previous code block

```
protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case Win32.WM_HOOK:
                {
                    m.Result = new IntPtr(1);
                }
                break;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? The hookProc Result from calling SendMessage is always 0. I have verified that the message is being received in the WndProc method and the m.Result property has a value of 1 when I call base.WndProc(ref m)

*** EDIT ***

Here is the C++ code I was trying to base it off of

```
static LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (code < 0)
    {
        return CallNextHookEx(hookHandle, code, wParam, lParam);
    }
    if (SendMessage(hwndServer, WM_HOOK, wParam, lParam))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hookHandle, code, wParam, lParam);
}
```

and

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_HOOK:
    {       
        return 1;
    }
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Parse the menu selections:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_ABOUT:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                break;
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not particularly familiar with c++ or WndProc and windows messaging in general, but I know the c++ code works and its just this functionality right here I'm trying to replicate.

Comment: The code is passing a pointer through lparam that is not valid in the process that receives the message.  Any attempt to dereference it (not shown, but surely intended) is going to cause an AccessViolationException.  Such exceptions tend to be swallowed, look in the Output window for a notification.  Don't pass bad pointers to get ahead, this is normally done with a named pipe..

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm aware there are some memory concerns in dereferencing the lParam, but I've also seen a few different solutions on how to resolve it. But for now the main concern has been figuring out why the message isn't returning the result and that's where I am stuck. Parsing the lparam will be my next step though for sure.

Comment: You let the call go to `base.WndProc` which is going to set its own Result